# How does git compare remote branch diffs to push changes

Tags: git, github

So, I have a this situation;

Both Local & Remote repository have this graph:

```
A <-- B <-- C  (master)
             \
              \
               D  (feature)
```

So, master like this:

```
A <-- B <-- C <-- E (master)
```

I do a `git pull` on master.

Followed by:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
```

Then a `git status` goes like this:

```
On branch feature
Your branch and 'origin/payment-app' have diverged,
and have 4 and 3 different commits each, respectively.
(use "git pull" to merge the remote branch into yours)

nothing to commit, working directory clean
```

**NOTE:** The error above is the original error i get from my real scenario.

So, my questions now are;

1. What exactly is happening causing this behaviour?
2. How can i solve this? I tried doing the `git pull` but i now get to have duplicate commits

Thanks!

Comment: I'm confused by you saying first that the graph has `master` pointing to the commit you have identified as `C`, but then saying that it has `master` pointing to commit `E`. I assume that *I do a `git pull` on master* means *I run `git checkout master; git pull`* but if that's an incorrect assumption that would also matter, answer-wise.

Comment: There was an hanging PR on the remote. I did not want to use D, think of the letters as the linear timing of the commits.

Comment: `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master feature origin/payment-app` tells the relationship between these branches. If `origin/payment-app` is the tracking branch of `feature`, `git rebase master` seems not a proper step though it's valid. A more common workflow is that you work on `feature`, pull from and push to the remote `payment-app`, and at last merge the latest `feature` or `payment-app` to `master` when `payment-app` is qualified. If you rebase onto `master` from time to time during the development of `feature`, the history gets nested and not clean.

Comment: I agree for this workflow, but i've run into this issue early before understanding better.

Comment: @Subomi.js Sounds like a case of rewriting shared history, but I just want to clarify that I understand the sequence of events before I answer. You made 3 commits on branch feature starting at (C) and pushed them to master as origin/payment-app (D). A commit was added to master (E) and you want to bring your branch up to date by rebasing those three commits onto the new master head. Is this correct? And are you a sole developer on a private repo, or is the remote branch public?

Comment: @Subomi.js If you have uncommitted changes, run `git stash` first. Then try `git branch backup-feature;git checkout feature;git reset D --hard;git rebase origin/payment-add`. If it goes worse, run `git reset --hard backup-feature` to restore. If it goes well, run `git branch -D backup-feature`.

Comment: @LightBender that sounds correct. I made a merge on bitbucket to the master. and did a pull into my master. And i want to bring my feature branch  up to date. Plus, i am not the sole developer of the repo.

Answer (score 1):

Git servers will not accept a push if it requires them to perform any action other than a fast-forward merge to bring your changes in. There are two options, which is best for you depends primarily on your workflow: rebase and merge.

### Current

[image]

### Rebase

Rebase will take your current commits and re-play them on to a new base as a series of new commits, (see below) the original commits will become dangling and be garbage collected in about 90 days (if you're using the standard config options)

```
git checkout feature
git rebase origin/feature
```

With this method, each commit may introduce conflicts that need to be resolved, but usually this is not an issue. It if occurs, resolve the conflicts add them to the and use the continue command, see [this article](https://help.github.com/articles/resolving-merge-conflicts-after-a-git-rebase/) for more details.

[image]

### Merge

If your workflow allows it, merge is a little easier to deal with if you have conflicts, but it makes the history a little less clean (there is practically a holy war between the rebase and merge crowd, so no opinions here).

```
git checkout feature
git merge origin/feature
```

This will create a new commit with two parents, your version and their version of the branch.

[image]

### Summary

Using either method, you can then push the changes to github because it will be able to perform a ff merge when it gets there.